# What does this statement mean: SELECT ... COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [-‌- Logins To Be Created --]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting, logins, collation

What does this statement mean?

```sql
SELECT ... COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [-- Logins To Be Created --]
```

It is part of a script I'm trying to adapt for listing out the SQL Server logins in an instance to be migrated into another instance. Here is the whole code:

```
 SELECT 'IF (SUSER_ID('+QUOTENAME(SP.name,'''')+') IS NULL) BEGIN CREATE LOGIN ' +QUOTENAME(SP.name)+
               CASE 
                    WHEN SP.type_desc = 'SQL_LOGIN' THEN ' WITH PASSWORD = ' +CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),SL.password_hash,1)+ ' HASHED, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' 
                        + CASE WHEN SL.is_expiration_checked = 1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END +', CHECK_POLICY = ' +CASE WHEN SL.is_policy_checked = 1 THEN 'ON,' ELSE 'OFF,' END
                    ELSE ' FROM WINDOWS WITH'
                END 
       +' DEFAULT_DATABASE=[' +SP.default_database_name+ '], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[' +SP.default_language_name+ '] END;' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS [-- Logins To Be Created --]
FROM sys.server_principals AS SP 
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins AS SL ON SP.principal_id = SL.principal_id
WHERE SP.type IN ('S','G','U')
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE '##%##'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT AUTHORITY%'
        AND SP.name NOT LIKE 'NT SERVICE%'
        AND SP.name <> ('sa')
        AND SP.name <> 'distributor_admin'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AS [-- Logins To Be Created --]` is merely a column alias for the result set since what is being selected is an expression, not a column. Expressions do not have a column name by default, so this is a way of labeling that result set column for cleaner output.

If you execute that query you will see that the single column in the result set is labeled:
`-- Logins To Be Created --`.

This has nothing to do with collation in any way. The  `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is potentially extraneous and unnecessary. If I remove it (from the query posted in the question) the query works just the same. However, in some cases (for other queries, not this one) a `COLLATE` clause/keyword is needed to explicitly force a common collation across all columns being concatenated (which is happening in this particular expression) *if* there are multiple columns *and* not all columns being used in the concatenation (or expression in general) use the exact same collation. In that case, without the  `COLLATE {any_collation_should_work}` then the query would get a collation conflict error.